# Limit result of inner join to 1

Tags: sql, inner-join, limit, sybase

I have this schema:

```
create table ord(id int);
create table orderpos(id int, orderid int, descr varchar(255));

insert into ord(id) values (1);
insert into ord(id) values (2);
insert into orderpos(id, orderid, descr) values(1,1,'huba');
insert into orderpos(id, orderid, descr) values(2,1,'blub');
insert into orderpos(id, orderid, descr) values(3,2,'foo');
```

So the data in ord looks like:

```
id
1
2
```

and in orderpos:

```
id  orderid descr
1   1       huba
2   1       blub
3   2       foo
```

I'd like to have:

```
oId opId    orderid   descr
1   1       1         huba
2   3       2         foo
```

but with this query:

```
select o.id as oId, op.id as opId, op.orderid, op.descr from ord o
inner join orderpos op on op.orderid = o.id;
```

I get:

```
oId opId    orderid   descr
1   1       1         huba
1   2       1         blub
2   3       2         foo
```

So somehow I have to limit the innerjoin, but how? I tried severel approaches found via google, but nothing seems to work.

**This seems to work in SQL-Editor of W3-Schools:**

```
select o.id as oId, op.id as opId, op.orderid, op.descr 
from ord o
inner join (select * from orderpos op2 group by op2.orderid) op on op.orderid = o.id;
```

And it seems logical to me that it doesn't work as long as you have different values in 'descr'. No clue why this works in the SQL-Editor on W3Schools.

Sybase version: Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.5/EBF 19902 SMP ESD#5.1/P/x86_64/Enterprise Linux/asear155/2594/64-bit/FBO/Wed Jun 6 01:20:27 2012

Comment: What is your logic for not wanting to select the `blub` record?

Comment: It would also help if you stated which Sybase database product you're using (eg, ASE, SQLAnywhere, IQ, Advantage) as well as the version.

Comment: @HoneyBadger To avoid duplicated records we only want to select the first record.
I updated my post with the version.

Comment: You do not have duplicates. If you want only one record for `orderid=1`, you have to decide which one you want to keep. 'first record' doesn't make sense, as there is no ordering. So how do you decide which record you want to keep? Also, did you try the approach suggested by @BHouse?

Comment: I have multiple records for the same ord, one for every description (one for 'huba' and one for 'blub'). I know that there is no ordering if I don't specify one. But it's not important for my business case. No, BHouse suggestion is far too complex to understand with my sql knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no logic has been provided for determining which row is the 'first record' (see @HoneyBadger's comments), and you've commented that ordering is not important for your business case, we'll use max() to extract a single row per unique orderid:

```
select  o.id        as oId,
        op.id       as opId,
        op.orderid,
        op.descr

from    ord      o,
        orderpos op,

        (select op2.orderid,
                max(op2.descr) as descr
        from    orderpos op2
        group by op2.orderid
        ) dt

where   op.orderid = o.id
and     op.orderid = dt.orderid
and     op.descr   = dt.descr
order by 1,2
go

 oId     opId    orderid  descr
 ------- ------- -------- ----------
       1       1        1 huba
       2       3        2 foo
```

Your join criteria between ord(o) and orderpos(op) remains the same; the addition of the derived table (dt) allows us to further limit the rows that are of interest from orderpos(op).

In this case it's just a coincidence that our use of max() generated the output you're looking for. [HINT: replace max() with min() to display '2/blub' instead of '1/huba'.]

---

Same idea but using a correlated sub-query instead of a derived table:

```
select  o.id        as oId,
        op.id       as opId,
        op.orderid,
        op.descr

from    ord      o,
        orderpos op

where   op.orderid = o.id
and     op.descr = (select      max(op2.descr)
                        from    orderpos op2
                        where   op2.orderid = op.orderid)
order by 1,2
go

 oId     opId    orderid  descr
 ------- ------- -------- ----------
       1       1        1 huba
       2       3        2 foo
```

---

Alternatively we could have replaced max(op2.descr) with max(op2.id).

The key issue being to pick some method ... any method in this case ... that allows us to pick a single row from op2 for a given orderid (via the **group by op2.orderid**).

NOTE: The proposed solutions work as long a given descr value is unique for a given orderid (eg, you can't have 2x rows in orderpos with the same orderid and descr).  If this is an invalid assumption then we'll need more sample data and/or a better description of the data in the orderpos table (eg, pk contraint, unique index, etc).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed solution. If I try your first approach and after the 3 from tables are some other inner joins, I'm getting the error message:Adaptive Server cannot perform the requested action because column 'abcid' is not within the scope of the joined table expression. I just added some inner joins after the 'from' and before the 'where' clause (e.g. inner join ABC a on o.abcid = a.id) Do I have to add all the tables from inner joins to the from and add the conditions in the where clause?

Comment: I managed to solve my problem with your approach. I had to move the joined tables to the from and the on conditions to the where etc. and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exists

```
select
  o.id as oId,
  op.id as opId,
  op.orderid,
  op.descr
from
  ord o inner join
  orderpos op 
on
  op.orderid = o.id and
  not exists
    (select 1 from orderpos op2 where op2.orderid = o.id and op2.id < op.id)
```

Comment: Hm, doesn't seems to work because I have other inner joins. I get the message: _Adaptive Server cannot perform the requested action because column 'productId' is not within the scope of the joined table expression_

Comment: @GarfieldKlon sorry for my english. I edit query. Please, try again.

Comment: Thanky you Okdel, this seems to work. Is it correct that this rely on the primary key (op2.id < op.id) ?

Comment: Hm, no doesn't seem to work. I have an example where I have 670 records. And with the updated query there should be ~300. But now with your query I only get 57. Which is definitely wrong.

Comment: @GarfieldKlon for all records in ord you have records in orderpos? if not, then try use LEFT JOIN instead INNER JOIN. About (op2.id < op.id) this code select records from orderpos with minimum id

Comment: not, not necessarily. And left join would even increase the number of results. But in my case it returns the same amount like inner join.

Answer (score 0):

You can select first row or one row by row_number fucntion

```
WITH x
AS (
    SELECT o.id AS oId
        ,op.id AS opId
        ,op.orderid
        ,op.descr
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY orderid ORDER BY orderid
            ) rows
    FROM ord o
    INNER JOIN orderpos op
        ON op.orderid = o.id
    )
SELECT otd
    ,opid
    ,orderid
    ,DESC
FROM x
WHERE row = 1
```

Comment: This seems fairly complex for such a tiny task?

Comment: I tried and I failed to implement that solution with my real world example which is using about 5 other joins. And even if I simplify my query I always get 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH' , so maybe this function is not available at this db version?

Comment: @GarfieldKlon If you could send me exact query (if possible), I will compose it for you. If you have any variables declared before with clause, you shoudl end it with ; sign

Comment: You could also just use this solution as a subquery instead of an CTE.

Comment: @GarfieldKlon; now that post has been updated to include your RDBMS (ie, Sybase ASE), this explains the 'incorrect syntax' error ... 'with x as (...)' is not valid in Sybase ASE; you'll also get a syntax error with the 'row_number() over()' construct ... also not supported in Sybase ASE

Answer (score 0):

That's what `CROSS APPLY` is used for:

```
SELECT o.id as oId, op.id as opId, op.orderid, op.descr 
FROM ord AS o
CROSS APPLY (   SELECT TOP (1) *
                FROM orderpos AS op
                WHERE op.orderid = o.id
                ORDER BY op.id) AS op;
```

It's a mix of a sub-query and a join. It let's you return multiple columns and rows for a row based condition.

EDIT. Noticed that it's not a request for SQL Server, therefore `CROSS APPLY` will not work, but this is normally being called a `LATERAL JOIN`, which seems to be supported by Sybase: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbreference/from-statement.html

Documentation has following syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM A, LATERAL( SELECT * FROM B WHERE A.x = B.x ) LDT;
```

So perhaps this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM ord, LATERAL( SELECT TOP 1 * FROM orderpos WHERE orderpos.orderid = ord.id) LDT;
```

Comment: `cross apply` is not valid syntax in Sybase ASE; and while `lateral join` is valid in Sybase SQLAnywhere it is not valid in Sybase ASE [NOTE: There are 4 different RDBMS products under the 'Sybase' name: ASE, SQLAnywhere, IQ, Advantage]

Comment: @markp Sorry, I realized that and was editing my question right when you commented :|

Comment: Evaldas: sorry, too; was also typing while you were editing :-)